# Copy settings between accounts in Windows 8 pro

Tags: windows-8

When I first started using Windows 8, I created a local account and set it up the way I like it, i.e. start screen, taskbar, desktop etc.

However, now I need to use a different user account, which means I'm now back on the default settings. I've copied the folders from the "user" folder across from one to the other, so I can access all my documents, music, pictures etc, but that didn't copy the settings, recent documents and so on.

Is there a way of getting all of the settings from my local user account copied onto the new account, so that I don't have to start setting it up again from scratch?

Michael

Comment: It is possible to convert a local account to a Microsoft one, if that's an option.

Comment: Is the new account local to the machine or on a domain?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Windows Easy Transfer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/transfer-files-settings-another-pc) to copy the settings and documents to a different account.

In the Wizard select to store the data into a transfer file. After the backup is finished, go to the 2nd account, run the Wizard again and select this is the destination PC and restore the settings from the file.

The Startscreen layout is stored in a file called `appsFolder.itemdata-ms` under `C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows`. If the transfer wizard doesn't copy the layout, copy this file into the new account.

Comment: This is interesting (except that the link to this service doesnt work anymore). Would it work for transferring programs (like MS Office, Adobe stuff) to the other user as well?

Comment: Windows Easy Transfer seams to be retired. It only copies data, not programs.

Answer (score 1):

Under Windows 8.1, the transfer wizard does not allow you to store the user settings  and docuents in a transfer file. Only importing a transfer file is available in the wizard.

Comment: Which image is that? :)

Comment: I can confirm that on Win 8.1, there´s no option to save my settings on a file. Just import them from Win 8, and Win 7.